# Unhandled Exception not being caught in Immediate Window of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, unhandled-exception

I have an event listener for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.ThreadException`. I am invoking a method from a `MODULE` in the Immediate Window that sets up the listeners and then throws an Exception.

1. Why does VS Immediate Window show that exception as a "First-Chance" exception and NOT an "Unhandled Exception"?
2. Why is my event listener not catching the Unhandled Exception?

My hunch is that the Immediate Window is doing something special here like catching all unhandled exceptions but that is just a guess.

Comment: The debugger steps in before your UnhandledException event handler can run.  There is no option to bypass it when you use the Immediate window.

Comment: @HansPassant - please make that the answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hans Passant:

The debugger steps in before your UnhandledException event handler can run. There is no option to bypass it when you use the Immediate window